# Issues installing Tailwindcss, specifically with "npx tailwindcss init"

Tags: tailwind-css

Im following the documentation but im stuck right at the npx tailwindcss init
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

[image]

Comment: Is your `practice tailwind` directory initialized as node project?

Comment: @Soyokaze yes it is

Comment: I dont know why but changing the directory worked.

Comment: yeah cuz some commands run on the basis of current directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check if your directory is initialized as a node project, i.e. it contains `package.json` file. If not then do this:

```sh
$/> npm init -y
```

2. Install tailwindcss as a dev dependency (optional as a dev dependency)

```sh
$/> npm i -D tailwindcss
```

Comment: Yeah i already did that.

Answer (score 0):

**Step : 1**
Correct you directory path like this `C:\Users\user\Documents\Web Dev\Tailwindcss_AlpineJs\pratice tailwind` then try this command `npx tailwindcss init`

**Step : 2**
Not working above **step : 1** then try this command : `npx tailwindcss-cli@latest init -p`.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue with the Nuxt Tailwind CSS module. It occurred because I had been using pnpm as the package manager. Switching to npm resolved the error. Additionally, manually installing the Tailwind CSS package and setting it up should prevent similar errors from occurring.